# View border Color not changing

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard, border, layer

I have a view I make border with this run time attributes:

[image]

The problem is `layer.borderColor` when I set borderColor my border is gone but when I don't set border Color I have a black border which I don't want
any ideas?

Comment: `view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor().CGColor`

Comment: For starters, "run time" attributes are set in code. Your screen shot is from IB - which is "design time". Show us your code and maybe we can help you. Also, what type of "view" are these attributes for? UIView, UIButton, etc. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are facing this issue because [`layer.borderColor`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410903-bordercolor) want `CGColor` and from `User defined runtime attributes` you can only set `UIColor` not `CGColor`, when you don't set the color it will take default `borderColor` and i.e `black` color. To set borderColor you need to set it programmatically like this.

**Swift 3**

```
yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor //set your color here
```

**Swift 2.3 or lower**

```
yourView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.redColor().CGColor //set your color here
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @NiravD suggested, you need to set both `borderColor` and the `borderWidth` on the view's `layer` to see the border.

**Swift 3 & Swift 4:**

```
circle.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
circle.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
circle.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

**in Swift 3.0**

```
  @IBOutlet weak var viewMainCell: UIView!

  viewMainCell.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
  viewMainCell.layer.shadowRadius = 5
  viewMainCell.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
  viewMainCell.layer.cornerRadius = 5
  viewMainCell.layer.masksToBounds = false
```